# Два onclick'а для кнопки

Tags: jquery, button, chrome-extension, greasemonkey

Кодю в TamperMonkey (Аналог GreaseMonkey, но только для Chrome) , столкнулся с такой проблемой. Если на кнопке `id=btn1` изначально в коде установлен `.on('click' ... );` , то `onClick` в TamperMonkey, сделанный мной, почему-то не работает! Как исправить это?

```
/*Сверху какой-то код*/

(function() {
    alert("1");
    $('#btn1').on('click', function () {
        alert("2");
    });
})();
```

При загрузке страницы выводит алертом '1', но при нажатии на кнопку почему-то не выводит '2'. Что делать?

Comment: А если обойтись без jQuery? Скажем, `document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', function () { alert("2");  }, false)`. Заработает ли? Не как решение, но так будет проще понять, в чём проблема.

Comment: Например, у вас нету кнопки с `id="btn1"`

Comment: @SurfinBird Омг. Заработало... Мда, и в чем тогда проблема? Вообще можно ограничиться и этим, но мне самому интересно)

Comment: @MrKlonwar, точно не уверен, но, по-моему, у userscript’ов часто [нет прямого доступа к переменным из скриптов страницы](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18818536/4267982). Увы, не могу точно вспомнить, в каких браузерах и с какими подходами. Хотя в данном случае и так и так надёжнее будет подключать из скрипта свою версию jQuery (вообще, как по мне, учитывая оверхед и то, что скрипт пишется явно не для какого-нибудь IE8, лучше будет обойтись чистым JS — с теми же стрелочными функциями и classList он довольно неплох).

Comment: @SurfinBird Хорошо, попробую большую часть на js написать) Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установить второй onclick удалось с помощью обычного JS

```
document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', function () { 
  alert("2"); 
}, false);
```